# Including html (not cshtml) as partial view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an `html` file used by both my SPA and the MVC viewengine (footer).  I'd like to share this but I don't know how to render the html file in the MVC.  `RenderPartial` doesn't seem to work - so I'm stuck with `File.ReadAllText`.  Is there a clean way to render an html partial with MVC?

Comment: Check [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871938/render-html-file-in-asp-net-mvc-view) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849207/rendering-html-files-as-views-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Html.Action**:

**View:**

```
<div>
     @Html.Action("LoadHtmlPage","Home", new { @path = Url.Content("~/Views/Home/Home.html") })
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult LoadHtmlPage(string path)
{
    return new FilePathResult(path, "text/html");
}
```

**Note:** This opens up a vulnerability as anyone could use that controller action to get any file on your website. The easiest fix is to apply the [ChildActionOnly] attribute to the controller action so that it can't be accessed directly by the browser