# jQuery.load doesn't work in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this line in my Razor :

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Home/index.html")))
```

And in HTML file, I have this :

```
<li><a href="#">Personal Records</a></li>
```

And in my js file I have this :

```
if ($(link).text() === 'Personal Records') {
    $("#govde").load("PersonalRecords.html");
}
```

But when I click on that link, nothing happens. When I open Index.html directly from file browser, it works. How can I fix this?

**EDIT :**

In console, it has this :

```
http://localhost:12345/PersonalRecords.html  404 (Not Found)
```

I guess I have placed the html files to a wrong folder. Can you tell me where to place? Thanks.

**EDIT2 :**

I have this in my JS :

```
var upperMenu = document.getElementById('upperMenu');
var requests = document.getElementById('requests');
$(upperMenu ).click(function (event) {
             ustMenu.childNodes.forEach((myList) => {
                 $(myList).attr('class', ' ');
             });
             var link = event.target;
             var list = link.parentNode;
             $(myList).attr('class', 'active');
             if ($(link).text() === 'Personal Records') {
                 $("#govde").load('@Url.Content("~/PersonalRecords.html")');
            }

});
```

`.load` function is created in this(seperate) JS file.

Comment: `$(a)` (not `$(link)`) but I recommend you give your element an `id` or class name rather than checking its inner text value

Comment: Check if you have any console errors? Also as @StephenMuecke said, we would like to know what does `link` hold! so try adding complete js code..

Comment: @StephenMuecke please see my edit. Thanks.

Comment: Where you've placed `html` files? Which directory?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I added the console error. Thanks.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao they are under ~/Views/Home folder. This is the place where the Index.cshtml is in.

Comment: @bhatunoglu Why not using `@Url.Content` with relative path to your HTML file, e.g. `$("#govde").load("@Url.Content("~/Views/Home/PersonalRecords.html")");`?

Comment: Why don't you write an `ActionResult` returning `FilePathResult` result.. as in `return new FilePathResult("PersonalRecords.html", "text/html");`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto For that, he might need to keep the `js` in `view` file rather than separate `js` file..

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto your code gives this error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I solved that error, but now I get this : `@Url.Content(%22~/Views/Home/PersonalRecords.html%22) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @bhatunoglu My bad... I don't see that your $.load is used inside JS file, hence you need to pass `Url.Content` result into a JS variable e.g. `var url = @Url.Content("~/Views/Home/PersonalRecords‌​.html")` and then `$("#govde").load(url)` (use function with `url` as argument).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto `var url = @Url.Content("~/Views/Home/PersonalRecords‌​.html"` gives `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` error. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: @bhatunoglu Try adding single quotes to mark the result as string (in Razor JS script tag): `var url = '@Url.Content("~/Views/Home/PersonalRecords‌​.html")'`. Then call the function inside JS file which receives `url` as argument to pass it, e.g. `outputHtml(url)`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I tried `("#govde").load(outputHtml(url));` but it didn't work.

Comment: @bhatunoglu You've misunderstood the instructions, I mean you need to create a function with `url` as argument inside JS file (e.g. `function outputHtml(url) { $("#govde").load(url); }`) and in your Razor JS code use this: `var url = '@Url.Content("~/Views/Home/PersonalRecords‌​.html")'; outputHtml(url);` (probably I need to write an answer explaining this).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto An answer would be great. Thank you very much.

Comment: @bhatunoglu 2 more things to confirm: for which `link` in `$(link)` bounds to (is `link` a JS variable instead of HTML element), and is the `$.load` function created on separate file instead of written in Razor `<script>` tag?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I have updated the question. Now it includes information about 2 things you ask. Thank you very much.

Comment: See this page:
[Render HTML file in ASP.NET MVC view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871938/render-html-file-in-asp-net-mvc-view)

Answer (score 0):

The problem started with file name mentioned in `$("#govde").load` method:

```
$("#govde").load("PersonalRecords.html");
```

This statement tries to load "PersonalRecords.html" which assumed exists in the project's root directory, but it returns 404 since the target file exist in different directory.

Hence, it should be mentions full absolute path URL to load HTML content first:

```
var url = '@Url.Content("~/Views/Home/PersonalRecords‌​.html")';
```

Then, since [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method placed inside separate JS file, putting them together should results like this:

**Razor**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/[path_to_your_JS_file]")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/Views/Home/PersonalRecords‌​.html")';
    loadRequest(url);
</script>
```

**JavaScript file**

```
function loadRequest(url) {
    var upperMenu = $("#upperMenu").get(0);
    var requests = $("#requests").get(0);
    $(upperMenu).click(function (event) {
        ustMenu.childNodes.forEach((myList) => {
            $(myList).attr('class', ' ');
        });
        var link = event.target;
        var list = link.parentNode;
        $(myList).attr('class', 'active');
        if ($(link).text() === 'Personal Records') {
              $("#govde").load(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, as of first mentioned part:

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Home/index.html")))
```

I considered this is not a good practice to read all file contents in view side, hence I prefer return the file contents from controller side using [`FilePathResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filepathresult.filepathresult(v=vs.118).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) like @Guruprasad Rao said:

```
// taken from /a/20871997 (Selman Genç)
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetHtmlFile(String path)
{
    // other stuff
    // consider using Server.MapPath(path) if in doubt determining file path
    return new FilePathResult(path, "text/html");
}
```

Usage as link in view:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("HTML File", "GetHtmlFile", "Controller", new { path = "~/Views/Home/PersonalRecords‌​.html" }, null)</li>
```

Similar issues:

[Rendering .html files as views in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849207/rendering-html-files-as-views-in-asp-net-mvc)

[Render HTML file in ASP.NET MVC view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871938/render-html-file-in-asp-net-mvc-view)